# WCF Service calling Domain Services - Domain Services reading WCF Service's web.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, domainservices

Recently I encountered a problem with WCF Service and Domain Services communication. The WCF Service calls a method on Domain Services, which then establishes a new database connection. It throws an error - connection cannot be created because the connection string cannot be found.
Now, the connection string it's looking for is present in the Domain Services' web config file, but doesn't exist in the WCF Service's web config file (so if I add the connection string to the WCF Service web config, it works fine).

Why is it checking the WCF Service web config file for this connection string? What can I do to stop it from doing this and ensure that Domain Services always use its own web.config, regardless of who the client is?

Answer (score 0):

The config will always be pulled from the executing project by default.

An easy way around this is to create a settings file instead of a web.config, which will be used from each of the projects. Ref [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to change the default behavior and have the config file not being pulled from the executing project?

Comment: Why do you want that behaviour? Can't you just add the config to the top level project's configuration file?